# Добавление DataTemplate в ListBox (DataTemplateSelector)

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, wpf-шаблоны

Пытаюсь сделать окно чата через ListBox, DataTemplate, DataTemplateSelector

Соответственно есть 2 темплейта

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="UserMessage" >
<Grid Width="500">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="30" Foreground="Aquamarine" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AssistantMessage" >
<Grid Width="500">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" Background="{x:Null}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<t:TemplateSelect          
                UserMessage ="{StaticResource UserMessage}"  
                AssistantMessage ="{StaticResource AssistantMessage}"
                x:Key="TS"/>




class AssistantMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

class UserMessage
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

И класс через который идет выбор Templat'a

```
class TemplateSelect : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate UserMessage { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate AssistantMessage { get; set; }


    List<UserMessage> SansData = new List<UserMessage>();
    List<AssistantMessage> WansData = new List<AssistantMessage>();

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is UserMessage)
        {
            SansData.Clear();
            SansData.Add(new UserMessage()
            {
               Message = MainVars.UserCommand
            });
            MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = SansData;
            return UserMessage;
        }
        else if (item is AssistantMessage)
        {
            WansData.Clear();
            WansData.Add(new AssistantMessage()
            {
               Message = MainVars.AssistantMessage,
            });
            MainWindow.Instance.MainChat.ItemsSource = WansData;
            return AssistantMessage;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

И добавление в ListBox

```
{
 TemplateSelect select = new TemplateSelect();
                        AppLogic.AnswerLogic.MessageTemplates.UserMessage UMData = new AppLogic.AnswerLogic.MessageTemplates.UserMessage();
                        AppLogic.AnswerLogic.MessageTemplates.AssistantMessage AMData = new AppLogic.AnswerLogic.MessageTemplates.AssistantMessage();

                        MainVars.UserCommand = null;
                        MainVars.UserCommand = MessageChat.Text;
                        MainVars.CommandToAction = MessageChat.Text.ToLower();

                        MainVars.AssistantMessage = "Сообщение ассистента";
                        select.SelectTemplate(UMData, null);
                        select.SelectTemplate(AMData, null);
}
```

Как добавлять сообщения, чтобы не приходилось удалять все предыдущие? Сделать как в чате.

Answer (score 1):

Вы делаете что-то совсем не то.

Функциональность `TemplateSelector`'а состоит в том, чтобы по данному элементу определить темплейт для него. Никакого добавления элементов во внешние списки быть не должно. Хуже того, это добавление мешает вашему коду и скорее всего служит источником багов.

Ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
class TemplateSelect : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate UserMessageTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate AssistantMessageTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is UserMessage)
            return UserMessageTemplate;
        else if (item is AssistantMessage)
            return AssistantMessageTemplate;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding тут привязка данных}"
         ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TS}" />
```

И добавление в `ListBox` должно быть не вручную (мы ж не на WinForms пишем?), а через модификацию данных, к которым привязано свойство `ItemsSource`.